# how to count different values from different tuples into the same sceme in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table of hospitals details, department details linked to it, types of workers (the staff) in different tables, and their salary information.

I want to extract the following for each hospital: the average and the sum of the salaries, the number of nurses, the number of research doctors and the number of beds in all the departments of a specific hospital.

I built this view of all the workers salary information:

```sql
    CREATE VIEW workers AS
    SELECT hospcod, docsal as sal, 'treatdoc' as typework
    FROM doc NATURAL JOIN treatdoc NATURAL JOIN dept
    UNION
    SELECT hospcod, nursal, 'nurse'
    FROM nurse  NATURAL JOIN dept
    UNION
    SELECT hospcod, docsal, 'rsrchdoc'
    FROM doc NATURAL JOIN rsrchdoc NATURAL JOIN lab;
```

the departments and the labs have the hospital code column to correlate a worker information to a specific hospital.
so I have one sceme for all the staff with their rules `workers(hospital_code, salary, type_of_worker)`

here is the query I'm trying to build:

```sql
    SELECT hospname, sum(workers.sal), avg(workers.sal), count(dept.numbed),
    (SELECT count(typework) from workers where typework = 'nurse') nurse_num,
    (SELECT count(typework) from workers where typework = 'rsrchdoc') rsrchdoc_num
    FROM hosp NATURAL JOIN dept NATURAL JOIN workers
    GROUP BY hospname;
```

I want to count for each hospital, the number of `nurses` and the number of `research doctors`
but it should be correlated somehow to the different `hospitals` (in the above it gives me the same number of nurses / rsrchdocs for each hospital) , there should be columns that is grouped by hospnames and should get all the tuples like the salary info (avg, sum), as I got properly, but the workers information should be grouped `HAVING typework = 'nurse'` for the `nurse_num`, and for the column `rsrchdoc_num`it should be `HAVING typework = 'rsrchdoc_num'`

does someone have an idea how can I combine thouse columns in one query?

thank you!

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your query, I will try to explain.

When you do:

```sql
(SELECT count(typework) from workers where typework = 'nurse') nurse_num,
```

You are getting a constant, that is not affected by the **"group by"** you are doing after.

What you have to do is a JOIN (like you did in the view) and link the **nurse** and the **rsrchdoc** to an specific hospital.
I will give an example is pseudo code

```sql
SELECT hosp_name, sum(nurse.salary) , avg(nurse.salary)
FROM hosp
JOIN nurse ON nurse.hosp_name = hosp.hosp_name
GROUP BY hosp.hosp_name
```

This query will give you 1 row for each nurse in each hospital (assuming that a nurse may work in more than one hospital).

Then you have to do the same thing also for doctors, in a different operation.

```sql
SELECT hosp_name, sum(doctors.salary) , avg(doctors.salary)
FROM hosp
JOIN doctors ON doctors.hosp_name = hosp.hosp_name
GROUP BY hosp.hosp_name
```

And finally you will have to join both ( you may perform the sum first to make it more readable.

```sql
SELECT hosp_name, sum_sal_doc, avg_sal_doc, sum_nur_doc, avg_nur_doc
FROM hosp
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT doctors.hosp_name, sum(doctors.salary) as sum_sal_doc, avg(doctors.salary) as avg_sal_doc
  FROM doctors
  GROUP BY doctors.hosp_name
) t1 ON t1.hosp_name = hosp.hosp_name
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT nurses.hosp_name, sum(nurses.salary) as sum_nur_doc, avg(nurses.salary) as avg_nur_doc
  FROM nurses
  GROUP BY nurses.hosp_name
) t2 ON t2.hosp_name = hosp.hosp_name
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be `1 to many` relationship between `hosp --> dept` and `hosp --> workers` so if you join these 3 tables then you will definitely find the duplicates for `dept` and `workers` so you must have to create sub-query for one of the `dept` or `workers` to fetch single grouped record `group by` hospital as follows:

```
SELECT h.hospname, 
       sum(w.sal) total_all_worker_sal, 
       avg(w.sal) avg_all_workers_sal, 
       d.numbed,
       count(case when w.typework = 'nurse' then 1 end) nurse_num,
       count(case when w.typework = 'rsrchdoc' then 1 end) rsrchdoc_num
  FROM hosp h 
  JOIN (select hospital_code , sum(numbed) numbed 
        -- used SUM as numbed must be number of bed in department
        -- COUNT will give you only number of department if you use count(d.numbed)
          from dept 
        group by hospital_code) d ON h.hospital_code = d.hospital_code 
  JOIN workers w ON h.hospital_code = d.hospital_code
 GROUP BY h.hospital_code , h.hospname, d.numbed; 
 -- used h.hospital_code to separate the records if two hospitals have same name
```